# HazelCast - How to insert records through a Map to a table with auto sequence field as PK

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using HazelCast to do read/write operations on MS SQL server database. 
I have a database table whose primary key is an auto increment column.
I read existing data in this table to a Map when my application starts. 
The Map has an underlying MapStore implementation.
The key of the map is the auto increment column value. The value of the map is an object containing few fields from the table.

User can insert records to this table through the HazelCast layer.
This insert is performed in a Transaction (TransactionalMap is obtained from HazelCast).

It is at this place i face a problem as i do not have the primary key value (auto increment value) to set to the TransactionalMap instance.
I have the insert to database table logic in the MapStore's store() method and the store() method is called only after commit is called on the Transaction.
I am not getting how to first set the key value (auto increment value) to the map. Auto increment value can be obtained post the insert to the table.

Ideas/Points are most welcome.

Thanks,
s.r.guruprasad

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `PostProcessingMapStore` interface on your `MapStore` which enables the ability to update the stored entry inside the `store()` method. You can obtain the auto-generated fields from the database then you can reflect those changes to your entry.

See Post Processing documentation : http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#post-processing-objects-in-map-store

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. However, the put statement on the map calls the store() in the store implementation. Hence, the key being passed to the put statement at the first place should have a new value, i.e., auto increment value. The documentation shows the id being set in the value object. How about change in the key? The code which calls the map.put statement does not get the auto increment value. Hence a later update becomes very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do what you ask is to have your code write a demo record into the database and then read it back before into Hz and making MapStore do an update rather than insert.
Of course this would be slow and cumbersome.

The best solution would be to turn off the autoincrement, but what you could also do is use a different field as the cache key, say have a member called cacheKey and store that in your database record, when you do an insert in MapStore you just need insert where databaserecord.cachekey == cacheKey.